# Using constants defined in variables in a function in tikz/pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am looking for a nice way to draw graphs of functions with constants that I can define outside, something like the below example

```latex
\defineconstant{A}{4}
\addplot{A*e^x};
```

I would like `A` to have a scope local to the axis/tikzpicture, I understand that I could define commands, but this is not locally scoped.

Comment: It is not clear, what you like to achieve. Is A constant (no a variable)? I will become more clear, if you will provide an example (MWE: Minimal Working Example) which will demonstrate, what you like to achieve.

Comment: I want to have a way to make constants that I can define for a plot, I feel like the code there is sort of what I want to achieve and I don't know what else i could add to make it more understandable

Comment: hm, `\def\A{4}`?

Comment: Something like `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage   {pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset  {compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\def\a{1}
\def\b{2}
\addplot[red,mark=none]  (\x,\a*\x+\b);
\addplot[blue,mark=none] (\x,\b*\x+\a);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`?

Comment: `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{declare function={A=2;}}
\draw[red,smooth] plot[domain=-2:1] (\x,{A*exp(\x)});
\draw 
(-3,0)--(2,0) node[below]{$x$}  
(0,-1)--(0,6) node[left]{$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to declare "constants", as you could already see from the comments below the question. Here I show three of them which are all local, i.e. you cannot use them outside the first `tikzpicture` environment. You can test that by trying to use them later again which will result in errors.

They are local, because I define/declare them *inside* the `tikzpicture` environment. That makes them local. If you would e.g. move the definitions of `\B` and `\C` before `\begin{tikzpicture}` then they would also work in the second `tikzpicture` environment. (Of course also `A` could be made globally available.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % define/declare constants using PGFs math engine
    /pgf/declare function={
        A = 2;
    }
]
        % define a constant using PGFs "mathematical expressions"
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{0.5}
        % define a constant using a LaTeX command
        \newcommand*{\C}{1}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot {A*\B*\C};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
% uncommenting the following lines will raise errors,
%        \addplot {A};
%        \addplot {\B};
%        \addplot {\C};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```